# How to make php file_exists work with Greek characters

Tags: php, character, file-exists

if the path contains a Greek character the file_exists will always return false, otherwise it works as it should.

(I display Greek characters all over my page with out any problem)

```
  if( file_exists($path) )
         return true;
    else
         return false;
```

Comment: What is the server's operating system?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows and for Arabic characters path, I have to change the system locals to Arabic in order to make PHP able to read those paths.